# jq doesn't grab correct file in a json

Tags: linux, bash, jq

I have a package.json

```
{
   version: "1.0.0",
}
```

And below is my content

```
version=$(jq -r '.version' package.json)

echo version
```

of my bash.sh file, but I couldn't get the '1.0.0', I got `version` printed on my terminal, any clue why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is bash, you are missing a dollar sign on this line:

```
echo $version
```

so you are printing a string instead of referring to a variable.

Comment: Please don't answer typo questions; just leave a comment and vote to close. Properly speaking, you generally want to [quote shell variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) for scenarios where the OP's data contains shell metacharacters etc.

Comment: ok, thanks for the comment. I will take to the heart.

Comment: but he helped me, can't we be kind to another human being? thanks @petrch!!!!!!

Comment: thank you both. It is always a balance between making the site work an individual and making it work for everyone. I understand that if we all stay organized, everyone will benefit from it.